# Replace dot, exclamation and ask sign with sed in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, replace, sed, terminal

I'm trying to use this code

```
sed "s/\!{2,}/\!/g" "s/\?{2,}/\?/g" "s/\.{2,}/\./g" file.txt
```

It almost work, but it doesn't replace the dot

-The input would be like

Hello!!! How are you?? .....

-And the output should be

Hello! How are you?.

Comment: Please show sample input and desired vs actual output.

Comment: And also what output you like to have from sample data.

Comment: hmm... sed -e 's/\.{2,}/\./g' doesn't work, but `sed -e 's/\.\.*/\./g'` does.  Does sed support the `{a,b}` style match count?

Comment: I want to change !! or more to a single !; and do this with '!','?' and '.' but it just replace the exclamation and the interrogation sign, doesn't work with the dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "Hello!!! How are you?? ....." | sed -r 's/\.+/./g; s/\?+/?/g; s/!+/!/g'
Hello! How are you? .
```

Answer (score 1):

add backslashes before the curly braces { and }

sed uses posix basic regular expressions, whose syntax require a backslash before braces (and grouping parentheses) to give them special meaning.
Otherwise it matches the literal characters { and }

```
echo -n foo | sed -e 's/o\{2,\}/o/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

my answer might  be a little "off tag", using tr seems the shortest route here

```
tr -s '?.!'
```

using tr with a file

```
 tr -s '?.!' < '/root/Desktop/test'
```

An example with echo

```
echo 'hello!!! my name is John...how are you??'| tr -s '?.!'
```

output

```
hello! my name is John.how are you?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# posix
sed 's/\([.?!]\)\1\{1,\}/\1/g' file.txt
# GNU
sed 's/\([.?!]\)\1+/\1/g' file.txt
```

use maybe class for 1 action for all at once